# Simulated Persons / thread going to a cinema hall with capacity 2 using semaphore

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I read about `Semaphore , Counting Semaphore` and based on the documentation, it says aim of `Semaphore` is to grant access to **multiple threads** to some **shared resource**, *at the same time*.

I tried to search online for a concrete example, but didn't find any.

I thought of a scenario, in which `Person / thread` watching movie. Now, `Cinema hall` can simulate a `shared resource` ,  which can be used by `multiple persons , threads` at the same time. I felt this would be a good example, to being with.

**In this quest, I created the below program.**

**Entry.java**

```
package com.example.threads.semaphore.second.v2;

import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

// This is the main "Entry" for thread
// which want to watch movie.
public class Entry {

    // Counting semaphore, with capacity 2
    // which means at most, 2 persons/ threads
    // will go into threatre.
    private Semaphore available = new Semaphore(2, true);

    private MovieWatching mw = new MovieWatching(available);

    // This method will allow person to go inside Cinema hall
    // by first trying to acquire semaphore.

    // The logic of person getting out of theatre
    // is dependent upon the Person itself, which we set in Main thread,
    // The flag -> "moveOut"

    public void access(Person p) throws InterruptedException {

        // This will consume a permit.
        available.acquire();

        System.out.println("Person " + p + " allowed to inside theatre");
        mw.watchMovie(p);
    }
}
```

**Person.java**

```
package com.example.threads.semaphore.second.v2;

public class Person implements Runnable {

    // This thread local would be used to make
    // person go out of theatre, and thus other
    // person can go inside the Theatre, who are trying to acquire a Semaphore.

    // Here Theatre represents a shared resource.

    private Entry entry;

    public Person(Entry entry) {
        this.entry = entry;
    }

    // This needs to be volatile as this field
    // is being update in main thread.

    // This simulated field visibility problem
    // when this isn't kept as volatile, then
    // the for(;;) loop in MovieWatching() mehthod
    // never comes out.
    private volatile Boolean moveOut = new Boolean(false);

    public Boolean getMoveOut() {
        return moveOut;
    }

    public void setMoveOut(Boolean moveOut) {
        this.moveOut = moveOut;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            entry.access(this);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**MovieWatching.java**: It represent threatre/movie watching.

```
package com.example.threads.semaphore.second.v2;

import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class MovieWatching {

    private Semaphore available;

    public MovieWatching(Semaphore available) {

        this.available = available;
    }

    public void watchMovie(Person p) {

        for (; !p.getMoveOut();) {
            // Movie watcing activity
            // unless person decides to go in the middle
            // the person will keep watching movie.

        }
        System.out.println("Person " + p + " going out now");

        // Now, make room for other waiting threads
        // who want to watch movie, waiting at Entry.
        available.release();
    }
}
```

**MainDemo.java**: Main entry point.

```
package com.example.threads.semaphore.second.v2;

public class MainDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Entry entry = new Entry();

        Person p1 = new Person(entry);
        Person p2 = new Person(entry);
        Person p3 = new Person(entry);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(p1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(p2);
        Thread t3 = new Thread(p3);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        // Making sure that t1 and t2 gets
        // into theatre.
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        t3.start();

        Thread.sleep(10000);

        p1.setMoveOut(true);

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
    }
}
```

This program seems to be working, a I expected, a sample example:

```
Person com.example.threads.semaphore.second.v2.Person@67ac2678 allowed to inside theatre
Person com.example.threads.semaphore.second.v2.Person@2204de0a allowed to inside theatre
Person com.example.threads.semaphore.second.v2.Person@67ac2678 going out now
Person com.example.threads.semaphore.second.v2.Person@7b2d84bd allowed to inside theatre
```

I have used `Semaphore` maiden time, so want to ask experts if this is what `Semaphore` is expected to do, and is my implementation correct (to simulate `Semaphore` granting `access to multiple threads` for a `shared resource`)

Comment: I'm too lazy right now to go into details, but after scrolling through it; looks fine. Maybe `volatile Boolean moveOut` in combination how you use it seems strange but that's a whatever. You may want to post this question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if it's working code and you just want some feedback, improvement tipps. It's not very on-topic for SO.

Comment: too verbose. Entry and MovieWatching  are in fact single object.